# Ajax is success, but Grails in JSON is null

Tags: json, grails, extjs, sencha-touch-2

In sencha, AJAX is always successfuly, but in grails fails whenever i try to recover him. It should recover in `def data = params.data`, and `def data = params`didnt work.

controller in sencha(on save)

```
onSave: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    var name = Ext.getCmp('name').getValue();
    var description = Ext.getCmp('description').getValue();
    var data = {};
    data.name = name;
    data.description = description;

    Ext.Ajax.request({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType:'application/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: data,
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/TryIt/product/newProduct',
    success: function(response, opts) {
    console.log('server-side success with status code ' + response.status);
    },
    failure: function(response, opts) {
    console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
    },
    error: function(msg){
    alert(msg);
    }
});
```

controller in grails

```
    def newProduct() {
    def data = JSON.parse(data)
    def newP = new Product(name: data.name, description: data.description)
    if (newP) {
            newP = newP.save(flush: true)
            println "saved!"
            println data.name
            println data.description
        } else {
        println "error"
        }
        return result as JSON
    }
```

Question is, how to recover the data that is handed to grails?
O yeah, js and jquery do this like rainbow and butterflies(works good).

Comment: That sencha touch, right? What version?

Comment: the lastest one 2.2.2 i think

Comment: can you print data in your controller, i.e. println(data); to see what controller received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed using `data = JSON.stringify(data);` and changing the `data` to `params` in my Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

If your request really is crossing domains, you won't be able to use `Ext.Ajax`, you'll have to use [`Ext.data.JsonP`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP-method-request) instead. But apparently it is not, or you wouldn't see it on the server side at all.

In any event, neither `Ext.Ajax#request` nor `Ext.data.JsonP#request` accept a `data` option. So your request may be leaving, but it's leaving empty. Check it in the network panel of your browser's developer tool.

Then, if you stick with `Ext.Ajax`, use the `jsonData` param instead of `data`, or with `JsonP`, use `params`.

Comment: Yeah, I've removed the crossDomain, and my data is returning json Object "{name: blabla, description: hehe }" normally. Ive changed in my Ajax the data to jsonData, but still in my server is giving me null whenever i parse it.

Comment: Do you see your request data in firebug, chrome dev tool, or the like? It seems more and more like a Grail issue, I won't be able to help with that unfortunately...

Comment: Yes, my data show in a JSON type in firebug, chrome console. Strange thing, that I have other project but not using Sencha Touch and works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the json data with:

```
def jsonObject = request.JSON
```

edit: I should add that it is already parsed into a `JSONObject` so you will not need to call `JSON.parse()`

Comment: How I know that the data is storing into the jsonObject?

Comment: Do you mean how do you know that grails has parsed the json and put it there successfully? A simple null check should suffice. If that's not what you mean, can you be more clear?

Comment: Well no success with the code you provided, It's giving me null object.